# List to SqlBulkCopy without datatable

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, sqlbulkcopy

We have a big list around 100000 records and want to insert it into a sql table.

What are we doing is; converting that list into data table and passing datatable to SqlBulkcopy method.

This conversion from list to Datatable taking more time. Tried using Parallel but as Datatable is not thread safe so avoided that.

Adding sample poc code which generates integer list and insert it into temp table

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> valueList = GenerateList(100000);

        Console.WriteLine("Starting with Bulk Insert ");

         DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
        int recordCount = BulkInsert(valueList);

        TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime);

        Console.WriteLine("Bulk insert for {0} records in {1} miliseconds.-> ", recordCount, ts.Milliseconds);

        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    private static int BulkInsert(List<int> valueList)
    {
        SqlBulkHelper sqlBulkHelper = new SqlBulkHelper();

        var eventIdDataTable = CreateIdentityDataTable(valueList, "SqlTable", "Id");
        return FillBulkPoundTable(eventIdDataTable, "#SqlTable");
    }

    private static List<int> GenerateList(int size)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(0, size).ToList();
    }

    private static DataTable CreateIdentityDataTable(List<int> ids, string dataTableName, string propertyName)
    {
        if (ids == null) return null;

        using (var dataTable = new DataTable(dataTableName))
        {
            dataTable.Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
            var dtColumn = new DataColumn(propertyName, Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
            dataTable.Columns.Add(dtColumn);

            foreach (int id in ids)
            {
                DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow();
                row[propertyName] = id;
                dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            return dataTable;
        }
    }

    private static int FillBulkPoundTable(DataTable dataTable, string destinationTableName)
    {
        int totalInsertedRecordCount = 0;
        using (SqlConnection _connection = new SqlConnection(CongifUtil.sqlConnString))
        {
            string sql =
                 @"If object_Id('tempdb..#EventIds') is not null drop table #EventIds
                  CREATE TABLE #EventIds(EvId int) ";


            _connection.Open();
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, _connection))
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            using (var sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(_connection))
            {
                sqlBulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
                sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = destinationTableName;
                sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
            }

            using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, _connection))
            {
                command.CommandText = "Select Count(1) as RecordCount from #EventIds";
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {

                        totalInsertedRecordCount = Convert.ToInt32(reader["RecordCount"]);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return totalInsertedRecordCount;
    }
```

Currently it is taking around 8 seconds but we need to make it more faster. Reason is our target is to insert 900,000 records which will be devided into 100,000 batch each.

Can you give us any hint how can we make it perfect and faster?

PS. Tried with Dapper insert too but it is not faster than BulkCopy.

Comment: So without seeing the code you expect us to suggest to make it perfect and faster? For starters it would help if you could state how much more perfect you want it? 30% or 70%? We don't do above 90%. And how much faster? Will under 10 minutes do? Our task would be somewhat easier if you would show the code that would need to be perfect and fast but I might as well tell you that code review questions are kind of off-topic here and might fly on codereview.se. This one, in this form, won't. So improve it first, then consider your options.

Comment: Using an [ObjectDataReader](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ObjectDataReader-8476dd72) instead of a DataTable will remove the overhead.

Comment: Agree with your point rene. Added sample code.

Comment: What exactly take 8seconds? Only the sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer method or the whole program? It seems to me a little bit high for only 100k rows.

Answer (score 0):

First Covert your list into XML something like

```
List<int> Branches = new List<int>();
Branches.Add(1);
Branches.Add(2);
Branches.Add(3);

XElement xmlElements = new XElement("Branches", Branches.Select(i => new 
XElement("branch", i)));
```

Then pass the xml to a SP as parameter and insert it directly to your table, Example :

```
 DECLARE @XML XML
 SET @XML = '<Branches>
<branch>1</branch>
<branch>2</branch>
<branch>3</branch>
</Branches>'

DECLARE @handle INT  
DECLARE @PrepareXmlStatus INT  

EXEC @PrepareXmlStatus= sp_xml_preparedocument @handle OUTPUT, @XML  

SELECT  * FROM    OPENXML(@handle, '/Branches/branch', 2)  
WITH (
branch varchar
)  

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @handle
```

Comment: Hi Abi, Tried this one. Inserting from xml is slower than BulkCopy

Answer (score 0):

### Bach Size

From what I understand, you try to insert with a BatchSize of `100000`. Higher is not always better.

Try to lower this amount to `5,000` instead and check for the performance difference.

You increase the amount of database round-trip but it may also go faster (Too much factor such as the row size are involved here)

### TableLock

Using the `SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock` will improve your insert performance.

```
using (var sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(_connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity))
```